# How to have separate recent projects and solutions list for Visual Studio 2017 and 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

My laptop has `Windows 7 64-bit` operating system. I have both `Visual Studio Community 2017` and `Visual Studio Community 2019` installed.

I am seeing that the recent projects and solutions list is shared between `Visual Studio Community 2017` and `Visual Studio Community 2019`.

For example:

- I open `Visual Studio Community 2017`, open a solution named
  **A_2017**, work on it, close it and finally close `Visual Studio Community 2017`.
- Then I open `Visual Studio Community 2019`, open a solution named
  **B_2019**, work on it, close it and finally close `Visual Studio Community 2019`.
- Now I open `Visual Studio Community 2017` again and check the *Recent
  Projects and Solutions* list and I see **B_2019** as the first entry
  in there although I never opened that solution with `Visual Studio Community 2017`.

Is it possible that recent projects and solutions list is not shared among different versions of Visual Studio? If yes please show how.

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same problem. When there are many solutions with different version requirements these VS2017 and VS2019 projects are confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I settled with a work around. For Visual Studio 2019, I installed this extension from the marketplace https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Danielku15.BetterStartPage2019

And created a group for VS 2019 projects and then added 2019 projects to that group.

This extension also has a version for Visual Studio 2017 as well.

Comment: This is great! Not only that StartPage in VS2019 looks like some kid created it, but also not changing long list of projects to something which can actually be useful when you have more than 5 projects on a computer (like what this extension does!)