# How do I stop visual studio 2022 and 2019 from sharing recent projects list

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

When visual studio starts it shows a recents list (and has one on the file menu).

Our team has VS2022 and VS2019 installed in parallel because we're migrating some solutions to .net 6 and want to leave the legacy projects maintainable on their own branches until we can release the migrated solution.

Unfortunately they show the same recent list which means that 2019 solutions are in the 2022 list and 2022 solutions are appearing in the 2019 list.

How can I stop them sharing the recents list?

[image: visual studio bug]

Comment: Did you figure this out as same issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue with VS2019 and VS2022.
Found a working solution that does not require any plugin.

In your VS2022 settings disable the "Synchronize Visual Studio..." setting seen in the screenshot below (Tools -> Options -> Accounts).
In VS2019 there is a similar setting but disabling this only in VS2022 was enough for me.
[image: vs2022options]

Not sure what other behavior disabling this setting causes. But so far I haven't noticed any problems.

Source:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Recent-projects-and-solutions-for-VS2019/10039684

Comment: For me, I had to uncheck that setting in both VS 2019 and 2022 to get the desired experience.

Comment: This didn't work for me. The settings are/were unchecked in both VS's but project/solution lists are synced anyway.

Comment: @RezaMortazavi Still working great for me in both VS2019 and VS2022. After unchecking the settings and restarting VS what happens when you remove projects from both lists?
Are they still being added to both VS's project lists when you open a project again?

Comment: one way not to show this screen is to go to the following root: "Tools/Option/Environment/General" and set the "on startup open:" to "empty environment"

Answer (score 1):

I tried the suggestion from [this Microsoft forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/829230/visual-studio-community-2019-and-2022-side-by-side.html), but removing a project from recent list syncs the change on both VS versions. At first I thought it worked but after several seconds, up to a minute, the change is synced.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57274875/how-to-have-separate-recent-projects-and-solutions-list-for-visual-studio-2017-a) suggest to use a [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Danielku15.BetterStartPage2019&ssr=false#overview) for customizing the Start page of Visual Studio, but it is only for 2019 and not updated since 2019, I choose not to try it, but can be useful to someone.
There is also an option to create a [custom Start page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-visual-studio-commands-to-a-start-page?view=vs-2017), but this seems overly complicated for me.

I did not found the issue logged in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/.